# Can some provide assistance on Resolving revoked Access Token error?

Tags: linkedin-api, access-token

I am using the LinkedIn oAuth 2.0 API , to retrieve posts , using /rest/posts API

I am able to successfully generate the access_token, refresh_token both,

```
 Object { access_token: "TOKENVALUE", 
expires_in: 5183999, 
refresh_token: "RefreshToken", 
refresh_token_expires_in: 31536059, 
scope: "r_organization_social,r_organization_social_feed" 
}
```

I have tried clearing cookies, changing browsers, Firefox, chromes,

but when I try to use the access_token to call the /rest/posts API, I get the following error,

```
{
code: "REVOKED_ACCESS_TOKEN",
message : "The token used in the request has been revoked by the user"
serviceErrorCode :65601
status : 401
}
```

Below is my server side method that gives the Revoked Access Token error,

```
def show_linkedin_posts(request,companyid,access_token):
    API_ENDPOINT = "https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?author=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A"+companyid+"&q=author&count=3&sortBy=LAST_MODIFIED"
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,'X-Restli-Protocol-Version':'2.0.0',"LinkedIn-Version":"202309"}
    api_response = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT, headers=headers)
    user_data = api_response.json()
    return JsonResponse(user_data,status=200)
```

A few days back the same code used to work. No changes done , no throttling of the API.